# Problema serialize/unserialize

Tags: c#, serialización

Cuando quiero deserializar me sale un la excepcion "Se llegó al final de la secuencia antes de terminar el análisis"

no se donde puede estar el problema.

De esta forma guardo los objetos en el fichero txt (adjunto parte del código)

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream Archivo = File.OpenWrite(urlDatos + nombreArchivo);
bf.Serialize(Archivo, user); //user es instancia de Usuario, este objeto lo recibo por parametro
Archivo.Close();
```

Luego para deserializar, por lo que pude ver en el último ciclo del while streamIn.Length vale 426 y streamIn.Positiion=421

```
        using (FileStream streamIn = File.OpenRead(urlDatos+nombreArchivo))
        {
            usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            streamIn.Position = 0;
            while (streamIn.Position != streamIn.Length)
            {
                usuarios.Add((Usuario)formatter.Deserialize(streamIn));
            }
            return usuarios;
        }
```

Comment: que contiene en urlDatos?

Comment: porque para deserializar tienes que usar un while ?

Comment: @Leandro Tutitni urlDatos simplemente tiene la raiz del directorio (es una aplicacion simple para un tp), el while lo use porque tengo que sacar varios objetos Usuario de ese fichero txt

Comment: pero la variable dice `url` a que raiz de directorio haces referencia? no le pongas a una variable `url` si vas a contener un path fisico a una carpeta de la pc local. Estas serializando a binario no puede cortar por objeto, serializas todos juntos y obtienes todos en una sola operacion, eso del while es incorrecto

Comment: Si serialializaste una `List<usuario>` esto es un bloque, tiene que deserializar esa misma lista leyendo todo el contenido del archivo

Comment: @Leandro Tuttini claro es yo serializaba de a un objeto por eso desp lo queria hacer con while  , entonces siempre tengo que serializar una lista??

Comment: @Leandro Tuttini yo cuando quiero guardar un registro, agrego ese objeto al fichero serializando, luego tengo varios objetos en el archivo y como los guardaba de a uno, tenia que sacarlos de a uno (esto entendi yo). Por esto deserializaba y habia visto que usaban un while

Comment: Me parece que el primer error es que serializas de forma incorrecta, no se guarda de a uno nada, si tienes varios objetos los unes en un solo gran objeto o lista de objetos y serializas todo en una unica operacion, asi despues al deserializar lo haces de la misma forma, en un solo bloque

Comment: Si quieres validarlo solo cambia el formato, serializa y deserializa a xml los datos de estos objetos y ve como responde, alli te daras cuando porque podras editar el archivo con el notepad y ver la informacion

Comment: Muchas gracias leandro, al final serialize toda la lista y luego el proceso inverso